# Logstash: How to split multiline json object and add_field into kibana?

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have the following JSON data, what I need is split each object into the separate message and add_filed, but with my current configuration, this whole JSON is getting into one message, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help or right direction will be really helpful.

```
[
    {
        "SOURCE": "Source A",
        "Model": "ModelABC",
        "Qty": "3"
    },
    {
        "SOURCE": "Source B",
        "Model": "MoBC",
        "Qty": "31"
    },
    {
        "SOURCE": "Source C",
        "Model": "MoBCSss",
        "Qty": "3qq"
    }
]
```

logstash.config

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/sample-log/Test-Log-For-Kibana.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => multiline {
      pattern => "^}"
      negate => true what => previous auto_flush_interval => 1 multiline_tag => ""
    }
  }
}

filter {

  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "someField"
  }

  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "SOURCE" => "%{[someField][SOURCE]}"
      "Model" => "%{[someField][Model]}"
      "Qty" => "%{[someField][Qty]}"
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "changeme"
  }

}
```